# помогите убрать Hover

Tags: hover

[image]Как убрать Hover с логотипа

```
.header {
    // padding: 70px 0 0 0;
    // display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    // height: 120px;
    line-height: 70px;
    background-color: #eff0f2;
    width: 100%;
    // margin: 0 0 205px 0;
    .header__container {
        display: flex;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .header {
    }
    .header__logo {
        line-height: 70px;
        margin: 20px 50px 0 0;
    }
    .header__icon {
    }
    .header__nav {
    }
    .header__list {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .header__link {
        font-size: 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000;
    }
    .header__list li {
        cursor: pointer;
        line-height: 90px;
        padding: 0 10px;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    .header__list li:hover {
        background-color: #a2dcd9;
        transition: all 0.5s;
    }
    .header__list li:last-child {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

```
    <div class="header">
        <div class='header__container _container'>
            <a href="#home" class="header__logo">
                <img src="img/home/header/Logo.png" alt="Logo" class="header__icon">
            </a>
            <div class="header__nav">
                <div class="header__list header__list_more-lg">
                    <ul class="header__list ">
                        <a href="#home" class="header__link">
                            <li class="_header__item">HOME</li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#about" class="header__link">
                            <li class="_header__item">ABOUT US</li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#work" class="header__link">
                            <li class="_header__item">WORKS</li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#services" class="header__link">
                            <li class="_header__item">OUR SERVICES</li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#team" class="header__link">
                            <li class="_header__item">TEAM</li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#reviews" class="header__link">
                            <li class="_header__item">REVIEWS</li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#partners" class="header__link">
                            <li class="_header__item">PARTNERS</li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#contact" class="header__link">
                            <li class="_header__item">CONTACT</li>
                        </a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: по коду ховеры только на лишках, а по факту почему то и на лого

Comment: ты походу что-то перепутал :) нет ховера, проверил у себя.

Comment: Ты скриншот видишь?